# How to know if the image still exists

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

My app creates an album, the user selects the images he/she wants to add to the album.

I store the selected images path in the database and retrieve those path and convert it into Bitmap and place them in RecyclerView.

My problem is that **what if the user deletes the images in the gallery but the path in my database still exists** how can my application adapts to this scenario because I only save the image path in my database?

Here's the following code that displays images in RecyclerView

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    static List<GettersSetters> dbList;
    static Context context;

    ImageAdapter(Context context, List<GettersSetters> dbList) {
        this.dbList = new ArrayList<GettersSetters>();
        this.context = context;
        this.dbList = dbList;

    }

    @Override
    public ImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_image, null);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Bitmap img = decodeBitmapWithSize(dbList.get(position).getPath(),300,150, true);
        holder.imageGallery.setImageBitmap(img);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dbList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ImageView imageGallery;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            imageGallery = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.img_row);
            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemLayoutView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Delete Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Check if the path is valid...?

Comment: check it from DB.

Comment: you can check if the file exists or not, whenever you are about to display the image.

Comment: just check everytime if the image at path exists or not before setting it to ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve the bitmap from the path, create a File Object and check if the file exists. Ignore it if it doesn't exist.

```
 File file = new File(dbList.get(position).getPath());
 if (file.exists()) {
    //draw the bitmap here
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like

```
    File file = new File("<your_image_path>");
    if (file.isFile()) {
    //do your stuff here
    }
```

Comment: what is imageName here?

Comment: @ChristineRamos changed my answer.